# counting missing values in a time series using R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a large time series dataset taken from a rain station with hourly intervals. To assess the quality of the data I'll like to know which days don't have the 24 measurements they should.

This is the structure of my dataframe where the Date column is already in POSIXct format:

```
     Date       Time      Rain
1  2014-12-05  10:00 AM    0
2  2014-12-05  12:00 PM    0
3  2014-12-05   1:00 PM    0
4  2014-12-05   2:00 PM    0
5  2014-12-05   3:00 PM    0
6  2014-12-05   4:00 PM    0
7  2014-12-05   5:00 PM    0
8  2014-12-05   6:00 PM    0
9  2014-12-05   7:00 PM    0
10 2014-12-05   8:00 PM    0
```

Is there a way in which I can count the number of rows each day has and then create a table showing the date and the number of measurements if these were less than 24 per day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(Date) %>% 
  filter(n() < 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
tab = table(df$Date)
tab[which(tab<24)]
```